# jQuery animate and property values in percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I trying to animate a div and I try to use some value retreived somewhere else, I know the value to be correct because I've printed out the output... so I'm wondering why doesn't it work properly?

```
animateBar(percentage.toFixed(2)+'%');

[ . . . ]

function animateBar(percentage)
{
    $('#innerBox').animate({width: percentage}, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems as though theres a bug with using a percentage with animate. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10669

I would suggest calculating the number of pixels to add yourself, something like this may work:

```
percent = 0.25;
add_width = (percent*$('#innerBox').parent().width())+'px';
$('#innerBox').animate({'width': '+='+add_width}, 3000);
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug still not fixed as of jQuery 1.10.2 as this is EXACTLY the problem i was having :/

Comment: Confirming this still happens with 2.1.0, but only when the parent container does not have a statically set width, and this fix works.

Answer (score 12):

This works if you're happy using CSS3 transitions:

JS:

```
function animateBar(percentage){
    $('#innerBox').width(percentage+'%');
}
```

CSS:

```
#innerBox{transition: 3s}
```

Comment: Fantastic solution!

Comment: Simple and optimized.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty old, but this way is working for me:

```
wthSelected = 85;
$(this).animate({
    width:wthSelected+'%'
  }, 1500);
```

Also i'm using **jquery-1.11.2.min.js** and **jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js**

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the units text like this:

```
function animateBar(percentage)
{
    $('#innerBox').animate({width: percentage+"px"}, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're allowing 2 decimal points to the percentage. Have you tried using an integer value instead? I'm not sure all browsers support floating percentages.

Also, make sure `$('#innerBox')` has a set `width` to begin with. It doesn't have to be a percentage. It just has to be set in CSS or through a JS method.

Comment: I have replaced the variable with a float number and it works fine, this issue is brought up only if I put a variable as property value.

Comment: And the width of `$('#innerBox')` is defined before the animation procedure is begun? It can't be `auto`. It needs to be defined somewhere, either as a percentage or as a pixel width.

Comment: I don't suppose you can link to the page in question?

Comment: Without something, there's no way I can diagnose. I've tried this in JS fiddle, and it works fine. I would just start checking things like your version of jQuery and ensure the proper value is being passed to the width.  Actually, that makes me wonder: where is your "percentage" value coming from?

Answer (score -1):

If it's in percentage then try this one here

```
function animateBar(percentage) {
    percentage = percentage+"%";
    $('#innerBox').animate({'width': percentage}, 3000);
}
```

we're using a css property here so don't forget the single quotes, so it should be 'width' not width

Comment: `'width'` vs `width` is irrelevant; it's interpreted the same by the javascript parser.