# Is there a way by which we can animate a div with percentage value?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a div containing 10 images in inline . on image load i want to give animate effect to div . i want to increase their size in % .there is no defined height in my css code . how to animate it .

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/simmi_simmi123/Pukjw/5/

**HTML page :**

```
  <body style="background-image:url('img2/Mesh2.png');background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
            <h1>iFlow</h1>


            <div id="container">
            <div id="center" class="column" style="  background-color: gray; opacity: .80; -moz-opacity: 0.80;height:100% ">        



            <!-- This is all the XHTML ImageFlow needs -->
            <div id="myImageFlow" class="imageflow" >


                <img  />
                <img  />
            </div>

       </div>

       </div>


        </body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.imageflow {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 100%;

    }
.imageflow img {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;

}
```

Comment: You'd have to preload them and get their dimensions to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer the SO answer for the same [jQuery animate and property values in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877081/jquery-animate-and-property-values-in-percentage) and FYI http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10669 would be helpful.