# parent().height() and 100% of parent height seem to be different values

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a footer section in a webpage, and found out that the jQuery `.animate()` method doesn't 'animate' when using percentages (apparently is a bug still not fixed as of jQuery 1.10.2?).  So, as suggested by [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877081/jquery-animate-and-property-values-in-percentage) I should use notation for the parent's height, plus `'px'` to allow jQuery to animate properly.  So I tried that, but this breaks the function :/

From my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYzT2/), I have this code:

```
$(function () {
 var open = false;
 $('#footbutton').click(function () {
     if (open === false) {
         $('#footcontent').animate({
             height: '100%'
         });

         open = true;
     } else {
         $('#footcontent').animate({
             height: '0px'
         });

         open = false;
     }
   });
  });
```

This works, except, the `#footcontent` div instantly pops open with no animation (but works fine when closing, as I have height set in px). Replacing `height: '100%'` with  `height: $('footer').height() +'px'` breaks the function, where for some reason jQuery now sees the parent's height at 0px and cannot make any changes in height.

How can the two be different?  I've tried replacing `$('footer').height()` with `$(#footcontent).parent().height()` and it's a no-go as well.  Surely I'm missing something  here or just being dense...it is 4am my time........

Comment: Your JS Fiddle link isn't working

Comment: i am totally lame at this hour, had the wrong link.  Try it now!

Comment: Whomever downvoted this, it would be great if you provided a reason for why.  Very bad form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that in order for percentage value to work for an element its parents height should be determined. Why not animate the `<footer>` height instead, works the same way.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/zYzT2/2/).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to animate max-height property, here using CSS3 transition:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tPaq6/)

```
#footcontent.open {
    max-height:500px; /*set bigger than it would ever be*/
    transition: max-height 0.6s linear;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.6s linear;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(function () {
     var open = false;
     $('#footbutton').click(function () {
         $('#footcontent').toggleClass('open');
     });
 });
```

Here using jquery animate:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6jrxY/)

```
$(function () {
     var open = false;
     $('#footbutton').click(function () {
         if (open === false) {
             $('#footcontent').animate({
                 maxHeight: 500 /*set bigger than it would ever be*/
             });

             open = true;
         } else {
             $('#footcontent').animate({
                 maxHeight: 0
             });

             open = false;
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Hmm, both demos will open but not close the footer div.  Also, do you have any idea why 100% would work (tho clunky), while getting the parent().height() doesn't?

Comment: Both demos for me work, closing footer div (tested on chrome). `parent().height()` cannot work because its height is currently the one you are not expecting, based on content