# Strange bootstrap progress bar behavior in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I've got a simple animated bootstrap progress bar in my app that's behaving oddly in Firefox only.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="render-progress" class="progress progress-striped active" >
  <div class="bar" style="width: 25%; height:100%;background-color: #CCCCCC;"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#render-progress .bar').animate({width:'50%'}, 2000);
```

In Chrome it goes from 25% to 50% like it should, but in Firefox it goes from 25% **to 75%** to 50%.

It's driving me nuts, I can't figure out why it's acting like that.

**SEE FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/dv4Hd/12/

Comment: @MageshKumaar less than what?

Comment: Set the width of the progress bar in pixels instead

Comment: It appears that 10% works. Weird.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877081/jquery-animate-and-property-values-in-percentage Although the bug referenced was marked fixed in '07?

Comment: I think this confirms its a bug issue with animate percentage: http://jsfiddle.net/dv4Hd/23/

Comment: @ChrisRockwell - I think you pegged it- want to make an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a jQuery bug regarding animating using percentages.

It is referenced [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10669) but marked as fixed for 1.7 - it reappears in 1.8.3 as changing the jQuery version to 1.6.4 or 1.7.2 in your fiddle will make it work as expected.

Additionally, converting to pixels works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/dv4Hd/24/

```
// Must include code when linking to fiddle
var $progressBar = $('#render-progress .bar');
var percentIncrease = 0.50;
var parentWidth = $('.progress').width();
var increasePx = parentWidth * percentIncrease;
$progressBar.animate({width:increasePx}, 2000)
```

I'll search the queue to make sure a report isn't already active, and submit one this week if not.

Comment: I've confirmed that pixels works fine, so I'm using that for now- thanks for researching the bug and the follow up- update us if you hear back from them

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.bar').animate({width:'50%'});
```

This seems to work properly 
But the time property is gone :/ !

But you can still get it up with transition delay :)

**Note :**
I am not sure, but I feel like if the time value in the animate function and the transition-duration is set to same values

```
$('.bar').animate({width:'50%'},2000);
```

and in css

```
transition-duration:2s
```

The animate seems to work properly :)

Comment: Interesting that the bug doesn't present when duration is excluded. Should help in debugging.

Comment: I am kinda confused. The bug comes from the time property or what? Interesting. isn'it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are animating upto only `50%` if you set less than this then you'll also face problem in chrome to [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dv4Hd/25/) because last position is that position and you are animating to 75% with css3.

So now your animation of 100% in jQuery would be equal to 75% in css. And then you'll not face the problem. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dv4Hd/26/)

Comment: Sorry not following your logic or what solution you're proposing. Are you saying it's impossible to animate to 50%?