# Unable to animate width of absolute positioned image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery 10.4.2 at the moment. I want to smoothly scale up an absolute positioned image. When I use the following code, I get no errors, but the animation does not occur. Instead, the image simply snaps to the full (`100%`) size.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <img class="scaleMe" src="img.gif" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box { position:relative; height:0; padding-bottom:61.6667%; background-image:url('background.gif'); }
.scaleMe { display:block; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; z-index:1; width:50%; }
```

JS

```
    $('.scaleMe').animate({width:'100%'}, 2000);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Here is a jsFiddle that works:  http://jsfiddle.net/s_d_p/27DhK/

But [here](http://secretdesignproject.com/demo/daosawan/7/) is a live demo that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you use $(document).ready(); or something to call your animation ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I *am* definitely using `src` atttribute on the image (now added) and the JS runs within a `jQuery(document).ready(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a src on your image tag.  Try:

```
<div class="box">
    <img class="scaleMe" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8yX/

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: With the src tag, it works for me in the fiddle.  Is it still giving you issues?  If so, what are they?

Comment: I still can't get mine to work. Here's a live demo: http://secretdesignproject.com/demo/daosawan/7/

Comment: I added links to live demos in the question above. I can't get the image to scale up. It just snaps to the final size immediately.

Comment: It's a bug with some jquery versions, change the percentage to a fixed pixel width and it works (or change jquery). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877081/jquery-animate-and-property-values-in-percentage

Comment: Any idea why it **does** work in the jsFiddle with the same jquery version?

Comment: In fact, I can't reproduce the problem on jsFiddle with *any* of the available jQuery versions. So I'm not sure which version to switch to.

Comment: You're using a custom 1.10.4, perhaps you left something out? Try your page with the CDN version of jquery and see if you still see a problem.  Btw, I did modify your code to use 1000px instead of 100% and it worked.  So, worst case, you can calculate the correct px value in the javascript code and go that route.

Comment: I'll check the jQuery version, but I think it's just named that because I exported a custom build of jQuery UI. Hard-coding the width in pixel values is not an option for me because it will break the responsive layout. I'm working on a workaround right now...

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of lame, but if I capture the target width first and animate to that pixel value and then replace it with a percentage it works:

```
var oli = $('.scaleMe');
var toWidth = $('.box').width();
var scaleUP = function() {
    oli.animate({width:toWidth}, 2000, function(){
        oli.removeAttr("style");
        oli.css("width", "100%");
    });
}
```