# Image size with percentage slows down site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A bit wired but this is the problem. I have jQuery animations and many other events that work properly when in my css file the image width and height are given in pixels but when I set them in percentage or auto (height: 100%; width: auto; --> how I need it to be), my whole web site slows down. The events don't trigger right away and my animations aren't smooth at all (I see only 2 or 3 frames of the animations). Any ideas what might be the problem or how can it be fixed ?

Example of my animations(left and right are divs):

```
  $("#left").animate({"width":"+=15%"},"linear");
  $("#right").animate({"width":"+=15%"},"linear");
```

CSS:

```
 img {
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12940695/2236219

Comment: I am not trying to animate in percentage the divs and images are not connected and can work separately, the problem is that the percentage and auto values to the images width and height slow down my web site.

Comment: @veili_13 Why do you *need* `auto`? Can't you go `width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: @HerrSerker I want my images to be as high as my container and the width to adjust properly to the height and I have more images in one container

Comment: Maybe this isn't related: but is the with a multiple of the number eight (8)? If not, try to cut the image to fit a width which is a multiple of eight.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have had site performance issues when using animations they have almost always involved images being too large. As you're using percentage sizing, it may not be immediately obvious that your images are much larger than they need to be.

The average desktop screen size is now **1366×768**, meaning that for most websites, the maximum image width/height should be **1366/768** for full-screen galleries (obviously less if these images are acting as icons/thumbnails).

Inspect your images' native dimensions in the developers panel, and make sure they don't exceed these dimensions: that may well solve your performance issues.